# Struggling to import JSON into excel where column includes records and lists

Tags: json, excel, powerquery

I tried using the import via the Power Query for a JSON file, but I'm struggling to pull the customer data I need.

Customers are stored as records with an internal ID and name.  For each ticket (unique rows), I may also have multiple customers linked. Therefore, when I look at the customer column, I see it contains both records and lists [image: which can be seen here].  Is there a way to use the Power Query editor to split those values out over a few columns or some other way so that I can see the customer names associated with each ticket row?

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to filter rows based on whether they contain a list or record, which should give you two tables (one table for lists, one table for records). Then handle/treat each table separately, before combining back into a single table.

For example:

```
let
    someTable = Table.FromColumns({
        List.Transform({1..3}, each [Customer = Text.NewGuid()]) & {List.Transform({1..2}, each [Customer = Text.NewGuid()])},
        List.Transform({1..4}, each [Contact = Text.NewGuid()])
    }, {"Value.Customers.Customer", "Value.Contacts"}),
    logicalMask = Table.AddColumn(someTable, "_hasMultipleCustomers", each Type.Is(Value.Type([#"Value.Customers.Customer"]), type list), type logical),
    rowsWithMultipleCustomers =
        let
            filtered = Table.SelectRows(logicalMask, each [_hasMultipleCustomers]),
            normalised = Table.ExpandListColumn(filtered, "Value.Customers.Customer")
        in normalised,
    combined = rowsWithMultipleCustomers & Table.SelectRows(logicalMask, each not [_hasMultipleCustomers])
in
    combined
```

- In `someTable`, I have a column containing records and lists, meaning I can't use `Table.ExpandListColumn` or `Table.ExpandRecordColumn` -- which I think is what you've shown in the image in your question.
- This approach changes the order of your rows. If preserving row order is important to you, you can add an index column (`1, 2, 3, ...`) before `rowsWithMultipleCustomers` and then after `combined`, sort by it to restore the original row order.